# XHR Request is pending until whole audio file fetch

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, stream, xmlhttprequest

I have a PHP music site that audio files played through java script :

```
audio.src = uri;
audio.load();
audio.play().then(

        r => {
            //set somethings
          
        }
    );
```

Recently when I play a track (with 206 response code) and immediately send another xhr request to server (for example loading a page through jquery.load)

```
$(target).load(path+"?ajax",function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){

        if(statusTxt == "success") { // callback response:

            //update url
        }
```

the request would be pending until whole mp3 file fetched (Chrome Network debug tab). I'm sure that this problem appeared recently and :

- My web server is Apache and keep-alive is active.
- No Matter that src of audio object be static or dynamic, both has this problem.
- I have no extra extension like ad-blocker on browser
- I checked it in multiple browsers (FireFox,Chrome...), also a different server.
- CSF Firewall is off
- I used read_and_close option to avoid session-locking.

And the strange thing is that **this problem is not exist on my local web server (WAMP Server).**

As I think Audio Object should send asynchronous request, where else I can investigate to find the cause?

Comment: @Yogi Is it important? I removed this block it and test again, no difference! But now suddenly I found out something strange : when I turn on [throttling] in debug console and make internet speed slower (3g), the problem wipe out. Can we conclude that send bandwidth of server is weak and total is using for streaming audio? The URL : zmix.ir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I did a test! In the waiting status, I opened a new tab and saw that new preview is waiting too! So I'm pretty sure it's related to server limitation or maybe web server but not the code.